# python unittest failing with relative import in source code

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have my python source code and unittest code structure in the following hierarchy:

```
bin/
    module1.py
    module2.py
    module3.py
test/
    module1_test.py
```

The code in the modules are as follows:
module1.py

```
from module2 import testMethod1, testMethod2
def testMethodY():
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

module2.py

```
from module3 import testMethod4
```

module3.py

```
def testMethod4():
```

module1_test.py

```
import unittest
import sys, os
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = os.path.join(path, 'bin')
sys.path.append("/bin")
from module1 import testMethodY

...(Some code for unit test)
```

when I run python module1_test.py
it fails with import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name testMethod4
```

Not sure what is wrong. If I run the source code then all the imports are working fine. But with python unittest these relative imports are failing. Can anyone tell me what mistake i'm doing.

Comment: Can you tell dir structure, like where is `bin` and other dirs?

Comment: bin and test are in the same dir /usr/lib/

Comment: Sandy -- I think you need to cleanup your example. Somewhere you are making a simple typo that is likely causing your problem, but there are too many errors to help. For example, `from module 1` (you can't have a space there. Also, you reference `testMethodY`, but your exception mentions `testMethod4`. Try to simplify this to the smallest reproducible example.

Answer (score 4):

Create an `__init__.py` module in your tests folder and add the following to it:

```
import sys, os
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = os.path.join(path, 'bin')
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

Comment: I already added the above code in my module1_test.py. But it doesn't work. Not sure what mistake I made.

Comment: When you say it didn't work -- what happened? If you are getting an error, post that in your problem description. The recipe I shared works perfectly in dozens of projects we manage.

Comment: I mentioned the error above:
    ImportError: cannot import name testMethod4

Comment: And no where do we see you importing `testMethod4`. Try to simplify your project to just a single module and single test.  Then try the recipe I shared. I assure you it it will work. Then build up from there.

Comment: Never mind -- I see your problem. Do what I suggested -- put the code in `__init__.py` in the `tests` folder and try your example again.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is a big project and I can't separate out for this test case alone. I see that if I rename the module3.py to sample.py then it is working. Looks like in the project there is a similar module with the name module3.py

Answer (score 1):

I think your `path` append statement is incorrect. You are appending `/bin` which would look for `bin` in the disk root.

`sys.path.append("/usr/lib/bin")`

Comment: I changed it as below
import sys, os
    path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    path = os.path.join(path, 'bin')

and still the same issue. Is it mandatory that there should be __init__.py in the bin directory? can't we import the file from package if it doesn't have __init__.py?

Comment: Yes it is, if you want your dir to be recognized as a package you need `__init__.py` as said below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of another module with the same name coming from python libs. I renamed it and that solved the issue. Another approach that helped is setting the module to PYTHONPATH.